# Sharepoint 2013 Variations contextual tab missing

Tags: 2013, variations

I have a publishing site collection with variation enabled(For en-us and fr-fr), When I go to Pages library of en-us site, In the top contextual tab area I can see two tab groups "Files", "Library" and "Variations".

For some reason I deactivated the Publishing feature first from site level then deactivated the Publishing infrastructure feature from root site collection level.

Now in the Pages library of en-us site the variation tab group is missing (Makes sense as publishing feature is not activated)

Now I have reactivated the publishing feature both at site collection feature and at site feature of all sites.

Still the variations tab group is missing.

How can I bring back the variations tab group?